# Insert data from select in multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have first database with two tables,

```
buildings
id city zip
```

and

```
buildingGallery
id path
```

These tables contains some data and they has relation one to one

I have second database that contains same tables with data. How I can added data from 
first db in another?

```
INSERT INTO [firstdb]..buildings
(city,zip,)
SELECT   city, zip
FROM     [second]..buildings
```

This script transfer data between buildings tables.But how I can transfer data in buildingGallery.

Update.

```
firstDb                                       SecondDb
buildings       buildingGallery            buildings        buildingGallery     
id zip city     id  path                    id zip city       id  path
1  22  minsk     1  somePath                 1  33 Moscow     1    somepath2
```

After I want get

```
    firstDb                                       SecondDb
buildings       buildingGallery            buildings        buildingGallery     
id zip city     id  path                    id zip city       id  path
1  22  minsk     1  somePath                 1  33 Moscow     1    somepath2
2  33  Moscow    2  somepath2
```

Comment: just do the same on what you did in table `buildings`

Comment: Table buildings and buildingGalery contains some data.So if I want insert in table buildingGalery I need know id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep following points in mind before trying this type of query

1. There is inter-connectivity between both the database, user that you are using to execute the query has sufficient permissions.
2. You need to specify the query in following format

`DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME` instead of just `TABLE_NAME`

Comment: Ok. But main question how I can transfer data in buildingGallery

Comment: don't you have a table for BuildingGallery?